# How we can use redis pipeline in django-redis?

Tags: django, redis, redis-py, django-redis

I want to use **Redis pipeline** (execute multiple commands) in django-redis.

We can use  **multi and exec** command in Redis but how we can in django-redis ?

**One solution is :**

I have list of hash keys i want to get all hashes using of hash key.

On every iteration command send to redis server to fetch one by one hash.

```
for hashkey in feedlist:
    result = con.execute_command('hgetall',hashkey)
    print(result)
```

This is not a good idea instead of this we can use redis pipeline. 
But how i can achieve Redis pipeline in django-redis ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Redis pipeline in django-redis.

```
 #first create pipline object using con object 
 pipeline = con.pipeline()
```

Inserting all commands into pipeline. 
Fetching all hash keys one by one and inserting them into pipeline.

```
 if feedlist:
     for post in feedlist:
         pipeline.execute_command('hgetall',post)
         #hgetall redis command to get all items of given hash key
```

Then call the `execute()` method on pipeline. 
It will return result back to result variable.

```
     result = pipeline.execute()
```

**Redis transactions**

> MULTI, EXEC, DISCARD and WATCH are the foundation of transactions in Redis. They allow the execution of a group of commands in a single step.

**Advantages**

- In one call we can fetch all the records.
- Reduced network calls.

---

Read also

[Redis transactions official doc](https://redis.io/topics/transactions)